# Emacs系のエディタを一通り学習する手順を教えてください

Tags: emacs, elisp, common-lisp, lisp

私はCommon LispとRacketを使うことができます。私はVimとDrRacketを使っています。

Emacs系のエディタとそのパッケージ等々、具体的にはGNU EmacsとSpacemacs, Slime, Lemなどを効率的に学習する手順を知りたいです。皆様からアドバイスを頂戴いたしたく、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Emacsについては、インターネットやその他の書籍に情報は多数存在していますが、なにぶん歴史の長いソフトウェアであるため、最新のバージョンには適さない古い情報が多く存在しています。

そこで、2017年に出版された改訂版Emacs実践入門という書籍を利用するのが比較的情報も新しく、初学者向けの内容であるため優れているかと存じます。

[[改訂新版]Emacs実践入門―思考を直感的にコード化し、開発を加速する (WEB+DB PRESS plus) | 大竹 智也 |本 | 通販 | Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/477419235X)

Spacemacs、Slime、Lemについては、いずれも開発開始から日が浅く、かつ活発に開発されているため、網羅的な日本語の情報は存在しないのが現状です。Emacsについての基本知識はいずれも必要ですが、まずは公式リポジトリのREADMEやWikiなどの情報を追うのが一番良いかと思われます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。kindleの無料サンプルを拝読させていただきました。まつもとゆきひろさんの寄せ書きもあり、大変意欲的な書籍であると感じました。